# Stop some of multiple animations on same element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have multiple animations on a single element and what I'm trying to achieve is to stop only specific animations when some conditions are met instead of all of them.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function anim1(){
    $('div').animate({left:'+=100px'}, 600);
}

function anim2(){
    $('div').animate({top:'-=100px'}, 400);
}

//When condition 1 is met
    // Stop anim1
    // Run anim2

//When condition 2 is met
    // Stop anim2
    // Run anim1
```

Comment: plase show your html code also.

Comment: It's just a single div inside the body with absolute positioning.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/ "As of jQuery 1.7, if the first argument is provided as a string, only the animations in the queue represented by that string will be stopped." And "If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element. These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately. If the clearQueue parameter is provided with a value of true, then the rest of the animations in the queue are removed and never run."

Comment: you could use `queue: false` to run multiple animations simultaneosly.

Comment: I want to run specific animations at the same time or separately depending on some conditions. .stop() whas the first trick I tried, it did not help me.

Comment: You might look into using an animation library for something like this

Comment: Would you please tell me the name of a library that could help me with this? I've had no problem finding lots of libraries but none that have the ability to do what I need.